# Jquery adding querystring parameter without page refreshing

Tags: jquery, querystringparameter

I want to add query string to URL without refreshing page using Jquery. Is it possible?

I don't want to use #.

sample:

http://test.com/prodcuts

after appending query string

http://test.com/prodcuts?name=abc.

I don't like below URL.

http://test.com/prodcuts#?name=abc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/
You can see some examples.